# How to stop multiple webclient DownloadStringTaskAsync

Tags: c#

I have a C# Windows Form Application that contains multiple `DownloadStringTaskAsync()` statements an example of which is shown. I want to create a stop button to cancel the complete function. I tried adding the code of `cancelasync` but it stops only one statement at a time and then it proceeds to the next.

```
private async void downloadfunction()
{
  string s1 = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url1);
  //do something with s1

  string s2 = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url2);
   //do something with s2

  string s2 = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url3);
  //do something with s3
}

private void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   client.CancelAsync();
}
```

If I press the stop button which fires the `stop_Click` function, it cancels the first download but then proceeds to the next. Is there a way to stop all the download functions with the press of a single click.

Comment: Read a basic tutorial about cancellation in .NET 4.0+.

Comment: Already read about the cancelasync function on MSDN

Comment: And your research job is not done there. Understand how cancellation works in general. https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en&gws_rd=ssl#complete=1&hl=en&q=.net+4.5+cancellation

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic way to do this would be to use a `CancellationToken` in your method:

(edit: courtesy Stephen Cleary, comments)

```
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
string s1 = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url1);
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
//do something with s1

token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
string s2 = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url2);
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
//do something with s2

token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
string s2 = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url3);
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
//do something with s3
```

Where `token` comes from a `TaskCancellationSource`'s `.Token` property, which you can then cancel via:

```
source.Cancel();
```

***in addition to*** `client.CancelAsync()`.

Note that many APIs allow you to pass a cancellation token *into* the call; apparently not this one, unfortunately.

Comment: `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();`

Comment: @StephenCleary d'oh! I checked for that... must have missed it

Comment: +1 Wrap the repetitive cancellation and download code in a helper function.

Comment: Any alternate way apart from checking at every step for cancellation?